# Should this file be created as .zip?

Tags: zip

I am calling an external library to create a file. I named the file as 'data' without extension. After the file is created, I run:

```
data myfile
```

It shows as " Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract".

Does this mean I should create it as "data.zip".

Comment: That's entirely up to you but it's not a bad idea as it reminds you what you need to do to read the file later.

Comment: So，the extension should be ".zip", not ".gz" and anything else, right?

Comment: "Gunzip is a Linux and Unix utility used to unzip files compressed in the gzip format. Although the gzip format differs from the zip format, gunzip can extract single-member zip archives, as gzipped files are frequently held within other containers, such as "tarballs" and "zips." If your zip file has multiple items, gunzip will not suit your purposes and you should use "unzip" instead."

Comment: So you mean I can use ".gz" as extension for my "Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract" as shown above?

Comment: No. As it may not be compatible if the zip file contains multiple items as per my last comment.